# The above gives the Chrome version How do we output the selenium version in java (i.e. Selenium v4.11)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The below gives the Chrome version
How do I print output the selenium version in java (i.e. Selenium v4.11)

I have successfully used the below to get the chrome version:

```
    Capabilities caps = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
            String version = caps.getVersion();
            System.out.println("Running Selenium version: " + version);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Java API does not provide a way to get the version of itself. So you probably need to see pom.xml.